# Android View performClick() and callOnClick() difference

Tags: java, android, view

What is the difference in usage between `performClick()` and `callOnClick()`? It seems that they work the same way, then why does `View` have two methods?

Answer (score 295):

The Javadoc for both methods is pretty self-explanatory too:

```
public boolean performClick ()
```

> Added in API level **1**
>
> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. **Performs all
>   normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility
>   event, playing a sound, etc.**

---

```
public boolean callOnClick ()
```

> Added in API level **15**
>
> Directly call any attached OnClickListener. **Unlike performClick(),
>   this only calls the listener, and does not do any associated clicking
>   actions like reporting an accessibility event.**