# onclick of one button calling functions of two other buttons simultaneously in android

Tags: android

```
REDLED.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        byte[] convertedBytes = convertingTobyteArray(
                IMM_MID_ALERT1);
        BluetoothLeService
                .writeCharacteristicNoresponse(
                        gattCharacteristic,
                        convertedBytes);

    }
});

GREENLED.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         byte[] convertedBytes = convertingTobyteArray(
                IMM_MID_ALERT2);
        BluetoothLeService
                .writeCharacteristicNoresponse(
                        gattCharacteristic,
                        convertedBytes);

    }
});
TWOLED.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       REDLED.callOnClick();
        GREENLED.callOnClick();

            }
});
```

I am doing a project to blink LED.I use two LEDs(RED,GREEN).REDLED button is used to blink Red LED and GREENLED button to blink Green LED.I want to work the two functions simultaneously by clicking TWOLED button.
But according to my coding

```
"REDLED.callOnClick();
  GREENLED.callOnClick();"

only GREENLED.callOnClick(); works.
otherwise if I code
"GREENLED.callOnClick();
REDLED.callOnClick();"
only REDLED.callOnClick(); works.
```

How to make "GREENLED.callOnClick(); and REDLED.callOnClick();work 
simultaneously when clicking TWOLED button.

Answer (score 2):

I think `performClick()` is the right method to perform particular button's click!

Know more about [what is the difference between performClick() and callOnClick() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250395/379693).

Comment: I am wonder if this will help from description both shouls call onClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this :

```
TWOLED.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       REDLED.callOnClick();
        GREENLED.callOnClick();

            }
});
```

to:

```
TWOLED.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             callRed();
             callGreen();
            }
});
```

Method definitions of `callRed()` and `callGreen()`:

```
private void callRed() {
byte[] convertedBytes = convertingTobyteArray(
                IMM_MID_ALERT1);
        BluetoothLeService
                .writeCharacteristicNoresponse(
                        gattCharacteristic,
                        convertedBytes);
}

private void callGreen() {
byte[] convertedBytes = convertingTobyteArray(
                IMM_MID_ALERT2);
        BluetoothLeService
                .writeCharacteristicNoresponse(
                        gattCharacteristic,
                        convertedBytes);
}
```