# Bottom NavigationView change items programmatically

Tags: android

I am using Bottom NavigationView and want to change items programmatically. There are 5 items and when I set 4th item selected, First item still remains active.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/color_white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_bar_menu"/>
```

Comment: You may check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202294/set-selected-item-in-android-bottomnavigationview/40721016#40721016, I believe it is very similar to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Viacheslav found the hack here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236786/set-initially-selected-item-index-id-in-bottomnavigationview

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From API 25.3.0,
you can use [setSelectedItemId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int))

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item_4th);
```

Comment: If you need to dynamically pass different Fragment arguments to the loaded Fragment take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57526788/4034572

Answer (score 2):

There is no possible way to change items through code currently but found the solution here 
[Set initially selected item index/id in BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236786/set-initially-selected-item-index-id-in-bottomnavigationview)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me
Saved me playing with fragments

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.my_navigation_item).setChecked(true);
navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.my_navigation_item, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method on Android 13.0. This simply changes an active item without clicking that item.

```
_nav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.my_first).setChecked(true);
```