# The first item in the BottomNavigationView keep highlight when I select other item

Tags: android, android-navigation

The first item in the navigation bar keep highlighting.

When I click other item on the navigation bar, the content will change but the corresponding item will not be highlighted, just keep highlighting the first item.

```
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment=null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.number:
                    fragment=new data();
                    break;
                case R.id.graph:
                    fragment=new graph();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_drawer, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

this is the listener

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:title="number"
    android:checkable="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:title="graph"
    android:checkable="true"/>

</menu>
```

this is the meun.xml

Comment: past your `menu.xml` file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236786/set-initially-selected-item-index-id-in-bottomnavigationview

Comment: where is the R.id.content_drawer layout

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens beacause of when **onNavigationItemSelected**  method return **false** value. You can check this with remove all code except **return true** inside the **onNavigationItemSelected** method. Just like this;

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {            
       return true;
    }
});
```

Then you'll see it works but the content was not changed. For change with content, If I were you I'll change the default return value as false like this;

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.number:
               //Open fragment or do whatever you want.
               return true;
            case R.id.graph:
               //Open another fragment or do whatever you want.
               return true;
        }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: So, this is very strange. I'm programming in Kotlin  - when I set the turn to just be true with no code, it works fine, but dong what you suggested just does not...

Comment: It's only a problem when the navigation items are selected by an outside BT mouse, no problem if touched by hand

Answer (score 0):

It is included in the Design Support Library, starting with version 25.0.0. You can include it in your build.gradle file with the following line (you'll also need the AppCompat Support Library as the Design Support Library's dependency):

**First use girdle compile both the girdle in your project**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

then create xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/darkGrey"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
```

Create a resource file just like a Navigation Drawer or an Overflow menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<menu  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_one"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
    android:title="One"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_two"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
    android:title="Two"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_three"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:title="Three"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_four"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder"
    android:title="Four"/>
</menu>
```

display image below:

[image]

To achieve different tinting for selected items, you should specify a color list resource as itemBackground and itemTextColor like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"
    android:state_checked="false"/>
<item
    android:color="@android:color/white"
    android:state_checked="true"/>

 </selector>
```

**Finally, you can listen to tab selection events by adding an BottomNavigation.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener via the setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener() method:**

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {  
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_one:
            // Switch to page one
            break;
        case R.id.action_two:
            // Switch to page two
            break;
        case R.id.action_three:
            // Switch to page three
            break;
    }
    return true;
   }
   });
```

try this code.

Comment: I have four footer icons. But for one tab it has many fragments. How can I make the tab as highlighted when onclick via another label in menu. For example the profile screen tab is highlighted when i am selecting the profile. Then I selected the home label in menu item. It redirected to the home screen, but still the profile icon shows as highlighed. How can I make this to change while moving from one frament to another  fragment.  Can u clarify this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986344/clarification-how-can-i-show-the-bottomnavigationview-tab-is-highlighted-if-the