# bottom navigation menu with fragment android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have an app with a bottom navigation menu and corresponding fragments. when I change among these of fragments, then I click on back button, it actually back to the previous fragment but the icon on bottom menu does not change. How can I back to the previous fragment with icon checked on menu
change as well.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set initially selected item index/id in BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236786/set-initially-selected-item-index-id-in-bottomnavigationview)

Comment: Same problem here @Cam, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to start learning navigation component

- It is easier, more functional and in general better for your application
- It supports the multiple back stack and it will manage all for you

You can get started from here :

- https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started
- https://medium.com/@muhamed.riyas/navigation-component-the-complete-guide-c51c9911684